# How to plot FFT of sine wave?

Tags: matlab

I have problem with plot of FFT signal

```
y=sin(log10(16)/log(6));
```

Here is my code:

```
y=sin(log10(16)/log(6));
Y = fft(y);
fs = 100;
P2 = abs(Y/length(y));
P1 = P2(1:length(y)/2+1);
P1(2:end-1)=2*P1(2:end-1);
f=fs*(0:length(y)/2)/length(y);
bar(f,P1);
xlabel('f[HZ]');
ylabel('|P1(f)|');
```

When I plot this code above, Matlab return me only a blue bar...

Comment: sin(log10(16)/log(6)) does not look like a sine wave to me, that's just some constant

Comment: Yes, but how I can plot this constant?

Comment: The constant or its fourier transform? Not that either is very interesting to look at in a plot..

Comment: If I have sin(log10(16)/log(6)), how to make FFT of this constant?

Comment: @Szymon you need to check your input data. `sin(log10(16)/log(6))` is just a single point. Its FFT is also a single point that is a blue bar on your plot.

Comment: @Szymon if you need an FFT of constant, use `N=100;y=sin(log10(16)/log(6))*ones(1,N);`

Comment: I use time vector such as t = (0:0.01:1)'; and plot FFT from sin(log10(16)/log(6)*t)